# исчез Регулятор громкости и звук после установки pulseaudio-equilizer

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, pulseaudio

установил pulseaudio-equalizer
на завтрашний день исчезла регулеровка громкости, но звук остался.
удалил и установил alsa-base и pulseaudio - И звук исчез
пробовал все что было в интернете
В настройках показывает только dummy Output

хотел бы вернуть хотя бы звук.
ubuntu 22.04, 5.19.0-43-generic